# Why does my iOS app show it needs "Local Network" permission?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xamarin.ios

In the iOS Settings app, my app has a list of permissions it needs. It also has one that it doesn't - **Local Network**.

I disabled that and it runs fine, so I know it really doesn't need it (besides the fact that I never use it).

So how did iOS get the idea that my app needs it?

(The app is built with Xamarin.iOS if that makes a difference.)

Comment: I guess, Xamarin creates a local server maybe?

Comment: some people others met the similar problem, maybe can make some helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119644/xamarin-ios-app-asking-local-network-permission-in-ios-14-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no related change to the project, that disappeared.

I assume it was something in Xamarin.iOS and was removed with some update.

So if you're facing the same issue, perhaps the latest update might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know your code and that there is nothing relevant there, then you have used some package that causes this. There is no third possibility.